# Can we import .py program in .c program?

Tags: python, c

I have to import the python program in a C program.

I want to use python functions in C which I wrote in a python program.

Please suggest some solutions or software that can do this.

Comment: There's a reason python is called python and C is called C.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed some Python code in your C program.
https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html